# Why does this Verilog counter design code have a syntax error?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, counter, system-verilog

I am a beginner in Verilog, and I am trying to design a counter. My aim is to increment the count value whenever I press the switch `sw`.  But, I am getting a syntax error at the second `if`:

```
else if (~sw & posedge clk)
```

The simulator did not provide any other details other than mentioning it is a syntax error.  I am unable to understand the error. Please help.

```
module counter (clk,reset,led,sw);
input clk,reset,sw;
output [3:0] led;
reg [3:0] count; 
integer temp = 0;
always @ (*)
    if (~reset)
        count <= 4'b0;
    else if (~sw & posedge clk)
        temp =1;
    else
        count <= count;
    if (temp==1)
        begin
            count <= count +1;
            temp =0;
        end
    else
        count <= count;
assign led = count [3:0];       
endmodule
```

Comment: What is the error? Also, you should use begin/end to group together what you want included in the in the always block.

Answer (score 1):

The second 'if' statement is not part of the 'always' block.  Try putting 'begin' and 'end' around the logic you want to group.

Comment: The 2nd `if` is part of the `always` block: `if (~sw & posedge clk)`.  But, the 3rd `if` is not: `if (temp==1)`.  Using `begin/end` is an improvement, but it does not solve the original syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

> else if (~sw & posedge clk)

It is illegal to use the `posedge clk` event control inside the `if` clause that way.

There are other syntax errors as well.  The indentation you used is misleading.  The `if (temp==1)` statement and its `else` clause are not part of the `always` block as your indentation would indicate.  It is illegal to have them outside of a procedure block (like an `always` block).  Perhaps you intended them to be enclosed within `begin/end` keywords under the `always` block.

Regardless of the syntax errors, that is an incorrect way to model a counter in Verilog.  Here is a much simplified version of your code which has no syntax errors:

```
module counter (
    input clk, reset, sw,
    output [3:0] led
);

reg [3:0] count; 

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (~reset) begin
        count <= 4'b0;
    end else if (sw) begin
        count <= count + 1;
    end
end

assign led = count;       
endmodule
```

This code uses an active-low, synchronous reset signal.  The counter is enabled only when `sw` is high.  The counter will automatically roll over to 0 if `sw` remains high for 16 clock cycles.